# Calculating P(A) given P(A|B,C), P(B), P(C), where B & C are independent

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

How do we calculate unconditional P(A) given P(A|B,C), P(B), P(C), where B & C are independent?

I've gotten to the below, but I'm getting a negative number, so I think there's something I'm doing wrong.

P(A) = P(A|B=T,C=T)*P(B=T)*P(C=T) + P(A|B=T,C=F)*P(B=T)*P(C=F) + P(A|B=F,C=T)*P(B=F)*P(C=T) + P(A|B=F,C=F)*P(B=F)*P(C=F)

Would appreciate any help. Thanks a lot!

N.B. A, B, and C are all events

Comment: First you need to be clear whether $A,B,C$ are random variables or events. If $A$ is an event and $B$ and $C$ Boolean random variables then your expression seems reasonable given the independence of $B$ and $C$

Comment: How did you get a negative number?  Probabilities are non-negative, and multiplying and adding non-negative numbers should give a non-negative result

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, Henry! A, B, and C are all events. I have updated the post above accordingly. I got a negative value for P(A|B=T,C=T) using this expression. I have all the other values, and I'm trying to solve for P(A|B=T,C=T) using this expression.

Comment: $P(A \mid B,C)=\frac{P(A,B,C)}{P(B,C)}=\frac{P(A,B,C)}{P(B)P(C)}$ here and everything should be non-negative (you also want the denominator strictly positive)

Comment: Hmm, I see. I think I might have miscalculated one of the values then, and I suspect the below is where I went wrong. 

Given P(X|Y,Z) and P(X) and Y & Z independent, this is what I did
P(X|Y=T) = P(X|Y=T,Z=T)P(Y=T)P(Z=T) + P(X|Y=T,Z=F)P(Y=T)P(Z=F)

Should have I done the below instead?
P(X|Y=T) = P(X|Y=T,Z=T)P(Z=T) + P(X|Y=T,Z=F)P(Z=F)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and sorry for the trouble!